# How To Use .NET to Count The Number of TIME_WAIT Connections on an EC2 Server

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, tcp

I run a few clusters of servers at Amazon EC2.  Lately, we've been running into an issue with the OS not cleaning up connection in a TIME_WAIT status, so I want to create an alarm to notify me when a server hits a certain threshold of connections in TIME_WAIT.  I can create a simple batch file to do this (netstat -an |find /c "TIME_WAIT" > count.txt), but the problem is that my monitoring software exists on my corporate network, so I don't have a way to call that command remotely.

I have a web server running in each of these clusters.  I'd like to create a web service that will accept the name of the server I want to check as a parameter, then make a call to each of those servers, returning the number of connections in TIME_WAIT status.  All of these machines are running Windows Server 2008.

In other words, a server on my corporate LAN will make a GET http request to a web server in EC2.  That web server will then remotely count the number of connection in TIME_WAIT on another server in EC2.  The EC2 machines are NOT in a domain.  Is this possible or is there an easier way that would save me the trouble?

An absolute requirement is that all of the calls and monitoring must be managed centrally by my monitoring application on my corporate LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up WMI counters in .NET, see second answer to this question:

[How can I access netstat-like Ethernet statistics from a Windows program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221181/how-can-i-access-netstat-like-ethernet-statistics-from-a-windows-program)

and this reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340(v=vs.80).aspx

WMI can be invoked remotely if the necessary credentials are in place.

Comment: I've previously tried using an SNMP approach that is similar to this, but it's not fast enough.  The program that runs the script have a max timeout of 60 seconds and with 40,000+ connections in TIME_WAIT, the script just can't process the info fast enough.

Comment: Well, then I think you are out of luck. TIME_WAIT is a state that usually last around 240 sec, which is defined by the OS. You could lower that timeout by a registry setting.

Comment: If you can count them when monitoring, I suggest that you schedule a job that creates a .txt file with the count that you can later read out via a webservice.