# How to get Network Statistics of a Remote PC

Tags: visual-c++, network-programming, tcp

H!
I have to make an application in vc++ which can get the network statics of remote PC.
Is any one can help me to solve my problem?

Comment: What are "network statics"? What information do you wish to be included? What operating system is the remote PC running?

Answer (score 1):

Since you said vc++, therefore, I assume that you have to do this in Windows environment. Have a look at [SNMP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol). And How it can be used to [get information of remote machines](http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/howto/snmp/vc/).

Look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221181/how-can-i-access-netstat-like-ethernet-statistics-from-a-windows-program) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the network statistics that you want to capture, you may find that (as Aamir suggested) SNMP is a good choice.

There are standard MIBs defined that will provide a number of network statistics. Three that are worth investigation are:

1. IF-MIB,
2. RMON, and
3. Etherlike MIB

[NET-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) is a good library for accessing SNMP information and is available for Windows (as you've mentioned vc++). Others are available.

This does assume that you have an SNMP agent running and accessible on the remote machines that you wish to monitor.

Comment: Thanks Aamir and Andrew...as both of you have suggested i am going to use NET-SNMP. If find further problem than i will contact you again.