# Which function is used in Windows Task Manager for Bytes Received/Interval?

Tags: c++, windows, taskmanager

I wrote an application that use `GetIfTable` function to show bytes recieved per second, but it doesn't work on windows7.

1- Which function is used in windows task manager to show Bytes Received/Interval?

[image]

2- Is there any library that get information about connection process and etc?

3- do you know any open source application like process explorer or glint?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221181/how-can-i-access-netstat-like-ethernet-statistics-from-a-windows-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task manager displays info from Windows Performance Counters.  The "Network Interface" performance counter object's instances are usually a computer's Ethernet adapters.  From these, it can get packets sent/received per sec, bytes sent/received per sec -- the same things Task Manager can show.

The code below accesses performance counters using the "PDH" interface.  First, create a `Query` object, then use its `SetObject` member function to tell it which object you want to use.  This example selects the "Network Interface" object, but you can see a list of all available objects by calling `Query::DumpAvailableObjects`.

When an object is selected, it auto-selects the first instance it finds for that object.  If you want to set a different instance, call `query.DumpAvailableInstances`.

You also need to tell Query which counters to show.  Use `query.AddCounter` to add names from the list of counters you get from `queryDumpAvailableCounters`.  The example adds two counters, `"Bytes Received/sec"` and `"Bytes Sent/sec"`.  But there are a lot of others you could try out.

Call `query.CounterPollingDump` to begin displaying data from the counters.  This is a loop which repeats forever until you Ctrl-Break.

To build the example, create a new console application and copy this into its source file.  I use Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <pdh.h>
#include <pdhmsg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "Pdh.lib")

static std::string CounterPath(std::string object_name, std::string counter_name, std::string instance_name) {
    PDH_COUNTER_PATH_ELEMENTS_A path_elements = {0};
    path_elements.szObjectName = &object_name[0];
    path_elements.szCounterName = &counter_name[0];
    path_elements.szInstanceName = &instance_name[0];
    std::string path(PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH+1, '\0');
    DWORD len = PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH;
    auto status = PdhMakeCounterPathA(&path_elements, &path[0], &len, 0);
    if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << std::hex << status << '\n';
        return std::string("Error");
    }
    path.resize(len - (path[len-1] == '\0'));
    return path;
}

using namelist_t = std::vector<std::string>;

// no arguments overload gives an empty name list
static namelist_t NameListParser() { return namelist_t(); }

static namelist_t NameListParser(const std::string& buffer) {
    namelist_t names;
    auto iter = buffer.begin();
    do {
        std::string name;
        while(iter != buffer.end() && *iter) {
            name += *(iter++);
        }
        if(!name.empty()) {
            names.push_back(name);
        }
    } while(iter != buffer.end() && ++iter != buffer.end() && *iter);
    return names;
}

template <typename T>
static void DumpList(const T& list, const char* item_separator=nullptr, const char* item_prefix=nullptr, const char* list_prefix=nullptr, const char* list_postfix=nullptr) {
    if(!item_separator) item_separator = "\n";
    if(!item_prefix) item_prefix = "    ";
    if(!list_prefix) list_prefix = "";
    if(!list_postfix) list_postfix = "\n";

    std::cout << list_prefix;
    bool first = true;
    for(const auto& elem : list) {
        if(first) { first = false; }
        else      { std::cout << item_separator; }
        std::cout << item_prefix << elem;
    }
    std::cout << list_postfix;
}

static namelist_t ListObjectNames() {
    DWORD buflen = 0;

    const DWORD detail_level = PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD;
    PdhEnumObjectsA(0, 0, 0, &buflen, detail_level, TRUE);

    std::string namebuf(buflen, '\0');
    auto status = PdhEnumObjectsA(0, 0, &namebuf[0], &buflen, detail_level, FALSE);

    if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return NameListParser();
    }
    return NameListParser(namebuf);
}

struct CounterNames { namelist_t counters, instances; };

static CounterNames ListCounters(const std::string& object_name) {
    DWORD counter_list_size = 0;
    DWORD instance_list_size = 0;
    const DWORD detail_level = PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD;
    PdhEnumObjectItemsA(0, 0, object_name.c_str(), 0, &counter_list_size, 0, &instance_list_size, detail_level, 0);
    std::string counter_buf(counter_list_size, '\0');
    std::string inst_buf(instance_list_size, '\0');
    auto status = PdhEnumObjectItemsA(0, 0, object_name.c_str(), &counter_buf[0], &counter_list_size, &inst_buf[0], &instance_list_size, detail_level, 0);
    if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return CounterNames();
    }

    auto counters = NameListParser(counter_buf);
    auto instances = NameListParser(inst_buf);


    return { counters, instances };
}

class Query {
    struct CounterData {
        PDH_HCOUNTER hcounter;
        std::string  name;
        std::string  path;
    };

    PDH_HQUERY               hquery;
    std::vector<CounterData> counter_list;
    std::string              object_name;
    std::string              instance_name;

    volatile bool keep_going;

public:
    Query() {
        PdhOpenQuery(0, 0, &hquery) == ERROR_SUCCESS || (hquery = 0);
    }
    Query(const Query&) = delete;
    Query(Query&& src) : hquery(src.hquery) { 
        src.hquery = 0;
        // std::move these if you want
        // this is really just for keeping hquery unique
        counter_list = src.counter_list;
        object_name = src.object_name;
        instance_name = src.instance_name;
    }
    Query& operator = (const Query&) = delete;
    Query& operator = (Query&& src) {
        if(hquery) PdhCloseQuery(hquery);
        hquery = src.hquery;
        src.hquery = 0;
        counter_list = src.counter_list;
        object_name = src.object_name;
        instance_name = src.instance_name;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Query() {
        if(!hquery) return;
        PdhCloseQuery(hquery);
        // Counter handles belong to the query and
        // don't appear to need separate closing by
        // the user.
    }
    operator PDH_HQUERY () const { return hquery; }
    bool IsOk() const { return !!hquery; }
    operator const void* () const { return (const void*)IsOk(); }

    void SetInstance(const std::string& name) { instance_name = name; }

    void SetObject(const std::string& name) {
        object_name = name;
        auto counter_names = ListCounters(name);
        if(counter_names.instances.size()) {
            std::cout << "Automatically selecting instance \"" << counter_names.instances[0] << "\"\n";
            SetInstance(counter_names.instances[0]);
        }   
    }

    static void DumpAvailableObjects() {
        DumpList(ListObjectNames()); 
    }

    void DumpAvailableCounters() const {
        if(object_name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "DumpAvailableCounters: An object needs to be set before calling\n";
            return;
        }
        auto counter_names = ListCounters(object_name);
        DumpList(counter_names.counters);
    }
    void DumpAvailableInstances() const {
        if(object_name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "DumpAvailableInstances: An object needs to be set before calling\n";
            return;
        }
        auto counter_names = ListCounters(object_name);
        DumpList(counter_names.instances);
    }

    void AddCounter() {}

    template <typename ...more>
    void AddCounter(const std::string& name, more... args) {
        if(!hquery) {
            std::cout << "AddCounter: Query was not successfully created\n";
            return;
        }
        if(object_name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "AddCounter: No Object Name selected\n";
            return;
        }
        if(instance_name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "AddCounter: No Instance Name selected\n";
            return;
        }

        CounterData counter_data;
        counter_data.name = name;
        counter_data.path = CounterPath(object_name, name, instance_name);
        auto status = PdhAddCounterA(hquery, counter_data.path.c_str(), 0, &counter_data.hcounter);
        if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::cout << "AddCounter Failed: " << std::hex << status << '\n';
            return;
        }
        counter_list.push_back(counter_data);
        AddCounter(args...);
    }

    void CounterPollingDump(DWORD polling_interval_ms = 1000) {
        if(counter_list.empty()) {
            std::cout << "CounterPollingDump: Nothing to do, the Counter List is empty\n";
            return;
        }
        size_t max_name_len = 0;
        for(const auto& counter : counter_list) {
            if(counter.name.length() > max_name_len) max_name_len = counter.name.length();
        }
        keep_going = true;
        do {
            Sleep(polling_interval_ms);
            auto status = PdhCollectQueryData(hquery);
            if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                std::cout << "CounterPollingDump: PdhCollectQueryData failed: " << std::hex << status << '\n';
                return;
            }
            std::cout << "      =======================\n";
            for(const auto& counter : counter_list) {
                const std::string spaces(max_name_len-counter.name.length()+2, ' ');
                std::cout << counter.name << spaces;
                DWORD counter_type;
                PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE fmt_value = {0};
                auto status = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(counter.hcounter, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, &counter_type, &fmt_value);
                if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                    if(status == PDH_INVALID_DATA) {
                        std::cout << " -- no data --\n";
                        continue;
                    }
                    std::cout << "CounterPollingDump: PdhGetFormattedCounterValue failed: " << std::hex << status << '\n';
                    return;
                }
                std::cout << "    " << fmt_value.doubleValue << '\n';
            }
        } while(keep_going);
    }

    void StopPolling() {
        keep_going = false;
    }
};

int main() {
    Query query;
    //query.DumpAvailableObjects();
    query.SetObject("Network Interface");
    //query.DumpAvailableCounters();
    //query.DumpAvailableInstances();
    //query.SetInstance("Some Other Ethernet Device");
    query.AddCounter("Bytes Received/sec");
    query.AddCounter("Bytes Sent/sec");
    query.CounterPollingDump(); // loops until you Ctrl-Break
}
```